# Passing user_data to callbacks class in Gtk.Builder.connect_signals

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

How can I pass `user_data` to callbacks defined in separated class. consider:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class CallBacks(object):
    def onQuit(self, widget, app):
        pass

class App(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(application_id="org.stof.example")

        callbacks = CallBacks()

        self.builder = Gtk.Builder.new_from_file("example.ui")
        self.builder.connect_signals(callbacks)

        self.register()
```

how can I pass the app instance to callbacks functions ? something like `self.builder.connect_signals(callbacks, self)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is possible, and the time is not my friend right now, so I've done a workaround, that's pass the app instance in `CallBacks` constructor.

`callbacks = CallBacks(self)`

`def __init__(self, app):` on `CallBacks` class.